# There is a problem with the if function that I am not able to understand

Tags: spreadsheet

I am trying to compare values from two different sheet in the same spreadsheet. However, my if function seems to be broken when working with the array variables. The if statement works with normal values but when working with arrays, it behaves as if the line was not there or something like that.

What is going on?

Here is the part of my code:

```
function addStock() {
  
  //declaring the used spreadsheets
  
  var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Stock Updater');
  var destinationSheet = activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Stock Record');

  //reading the rows in source sheet

  var sourceLastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1;
  var sourceLastCol = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

  var stockDates = sourceSheet.getRange(2,1,sourceLastRow,1).getValues();
  Logger.log(stockDates);

  var sourceProductID = sourceSheet.getRange(2,2,sourceLastRow,1).getValues();
  Logger.log(sourceProductID);

  var sourceProductName = sourceSheet.getRange(2,3,sourceLastRow,1).getValues();
  Logger.log(sourceProductName);

  var sourceQuantityToAdd = sourceSheet.getRange(2,4,sourceLastRow,1).getValues();
  Logger.log(sourceQuantityToAdd);


  // check if the product is already availale in inventory

  var destinationLastRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow()-1;
  var destinationLastCol = destinationSheet.getLastColumn();

  var destinationProductID = destinationSheet.getRange(2,2,destinationLastRow,1).getValues();
  Logger.log(destinationProductID);

  // gloablising loop variables
  var i;
  var j;

   //when my for condition was like: (i=0;i<sourceLastRow;i++), it wouldn't even log the ("SourceProductID: "+sourceProductID[i]. Same was the case with destinationProductID as well. But using .length I was able to log them. Why would be that?
  for(i=0;i<sourceProductID.length;i++){  
    Logger.log("SourceProductID: "+sourceProductID[i]);
    for(j=0;j<destinationProductID.length;j++){
      Logger.log("DestinationProductID:"+destinationProductID[j]);
      if(destinationProductID[j] === sourceProductID[i]){
      Logger.log("Product already in Inventory");
      }
    }
  }

  for(a=0;a<5;a++){
    for(b=0;b<5;b++){
      if(a==b){
        Logger.log("Match found");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you log `sourceLastRow` and `sourceLastCol`. Also, can you paste some of your logs?

Comment: they give me the rows and columns numbers that contains the actual data. if I have 10 rows and 5 columns with data, it gives me 10 and 5.

I got the idea now though, what was happening is that getValues gives me two dimensional array, while my coding is per one dimensional arrays. Need to check how we deal with two dimensional arrays and then we can solve this.

Comment: for(i=0;i<sourceLastRow;i++){
    for(j=0; j<1; j++){
      
      for(k=0; k<destinationLastRow; k++){
        for(l=0; l<1; l++){
          if(sourceProductID[i][j] == destinationProductID[k][l]){
            Logger.log('Match Found');
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }


This solves my issue. However, I think it will be pretty hard to work around data with this approach. Need to look for easy way again.